# Run continuous action when button is pressed

Tags: android, runnable

I'm trying to do this. When I touch a button and I keep pressing on it, it must perform an action, and this action will only stop when I stop pressing it.

To achieve this, I got this code:

```
btn_gas.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    private Handler mHandler;
    @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (mHandler != null) return true;
                mHandler = new Handler();
                mHandler.postDelayed(mAction, 10);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (mHandler == null) return true;
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mAction);
                mHandler = null;
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
    Runnable mAction = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do continuous task.
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };
});
```

But it isn't working as expected i.e. it performs the action continuously when I click on the button, even without me pressing on it continuously. To stop the action, I had to touch the button again.

How can I achieve the functionality I need?

Comment: How about you return `true` instead of `false` in `onTouch()`? Or to be more specific: You should return `true` for `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` and `false` for all other cases.

Comment: if you `ACTION_UP` while the mAction is running, the callback is not there yet and the `removeCallbacks` has no effect. I would add a test in the `run` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic for when you return `true` and `false` are reversed. Return `true` if you want to get future events, the `ACTION_UP` in this case. In fact, for a button you should be safe always returning true.  Also, you do not need to keep reallocating your `Handler`.

```
   private Handler mHandler = new Handler ();
    btn_gas.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mHandler.postDelayed(mAction, 10);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mAction);
                break;
        }

        return true;

    }
    Runnable mAction = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do continuous task.
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };
});`
```

Comment: I set the handler as you say, but If I use your code, the app continues having the same behaviour, furthermore, each time I pulse the botton the speed increases, this is, the the action is done in less time.

Comment: Solved just changing the return false for a return true.

Comment: You are right! I said always return true and even wrote false in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Returning false in onTouch means that the View is not interested in subsequent events. That means that your onTouch is only called once, registers an ACTION_DOWN event, starts whatever you want to do and is not called anymore. Reference: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

> Beware of creating a listener that returns false for the ACTION_DOWN
>   event. If you do this, the listener will not be called for the
>   subsequent ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP string of events. This is because
>   ACTION_DOWN is the starting point for all touch events.

Comment: Could you modify the code according to your explanation?

Comment: I have no time to test ist right now, but I guess the solution should be to just invert your return value, like Xaver said. Don't know about your Handler logic though.